# Use separate history for PowerShell session

Tags: command-line, powershell, history

I use Microsoft's [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) for remoting into machines (usually with [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) for Windows), managing [Git](https://git-scm.com/) repositories, and running commands in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (and other things).

I usually use command history to go back and select SSH commands for remoting, but after long sessions with Git or VS Code the SSH history ends up being pretty far back. Is there a way to launch PowerShell with a different history file so that the command history is different for each task?

There is a history file stored in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt`, so maybe there's an environment variable or command line switch that can set it to a different location for the session (by launching PowerShell through a [batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) file for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the history file location with [Set-PSReadlineOption](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-6).  If you want to switch you could make a couple of `.ps1` files, for example:

*History1.ps1* containing

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -HistorySavePath 'C:\Users\Hali\Desktop\History1.txt'
```

*DefaultHistory.ps1* containing

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -HistorySavePath 'C:\Users\Hali\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt'
```

and create aliases to them.  For example:

```
Set-Alias -Name History1 -Value 'C:\<path to>\History1.ps1'
Set-Alias -Name DefaultHistory -Value 'C:\<path to>\DefaultHistory.ps1'
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I stuck `start powershell -noexit Set-PSReadlineOption -HistorySavePath 'History SSH.txt'` in a batch file and now I have an easy way to open shells with different histories.